# Pixelstick wireless remote trigger alternative

Tags: remote, wireless-triggers

I got a pixelstick (http://www.thepixelstick.com/) and want to see what options I have to trigger it remotely.

They sell a remote trigger that goes with the pixelstick ( http://order.thepixelstick.com/add-ons/ ), but I have given up asking them to let me purchase one. I tried to get them to add it to my order I made 6+ months ago (kickstarter campaign)... never got a response. I made my original order before they had the add-on available. Anyway...

Does anyone recognize the brand of the trigger? http://order.thepixelstick.com/add-ons/ There is a female mini plug on the pixelstick that the remote trigger plugs into.

Suggestions? Alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like an IR controller, which can easily be copied, but you need the original to copy the signal. You could just try different combinations - try your TV remote on it. Try the WatchON app, which can emulate many brands of TV remotes. If it's Bluetooth or Wi-Fi - again, we can hack that but someone will need to examine the device itself to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a lot like [the Pixel Oppilas remote](http://www.pixelhk.com/Proshow.aspx?id=300); you can find it on Amazon. Pixel makes the shutter release cables with nearly any connector you could need.  Basically, most of the folks who make cheap flash radio triggers also make cheap radio shutter releases as well. If you already have cheap radio flash triggers (e.g., Yongnuo RF-603II triggers, Cactus V5, etc.), many of them can also do double-duty as remote shutter releases--it's usually just a matter of pairing the trigger with the appropriate cable with a shutter release connector that matches your camera.

My experience with Pixel has been mixed.  A cheap cable release for my Panasonic G3 arrived broken.  But the Pixel Panasonic cable that I use with my TriggerTrap dongle works just fine.